# HTML: Stream video in browser without making it easy to download mp4

Tags: html, video, youtube, embed

Apparently I used the totally wrong keywords while googling because Im looking for solutions on how to embed videos in my webpage and still make "impossible" (i.e. make it hard) to download these directly as a mp4 file. I mean there are various players where you'll quite easily find out the original file on the webserver directly within the browser...

And on the opposite there are pages like youtube where you cannot really find out the full file but you'd have to use third party solutions to download the files.

Do you know any libraries / modules which support embedding in such a way like youtube?
Thanks

Comment: You could always upload to YouTube and use their embedding code.

Comment: Yes but Id like to keep the videos on my server - is there an alternative?

Comment: `document.querySelector('video').oncontextmenu = function(){ return false }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really is not that hard to download/capture the file if you are making it available to stream to a device, even for YouTube videos, so you have to consider what your goals are.

Most content protection systems, or Digital Rights Management systems, don't really attempt to stop someone capturing the file. Rather they try to ensure that the captured file is of no use by having it encrypted so it cannot play back.

The tricky part then moves to securely sharing the decryption key with authorised users in a way that neither they nor a third party can view or share the key. This is the essence of nearly all common DRM systems.

If you do want to use DRM but don't want to pay for a full DRM solution then you could use clear key encryption with MPEG-DASH streaming. This essentially transmits the key with the stream so it not very secure, but it may meet your needs. There is some info on using it with a cloud encoding service here:

- https://bitmovin.com/tutorials/mpeg-cenc-clearkey-drm-encryption/